# How to make mutual methods for different classes?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I want to make a corpus of text (English and Ukrainian). I want to get the words of the corpus by passing the author to the method "words" via "Corpus.ENG_Lullabies". When I do that I get an error. I could make separate methods for both of the classes but the function is the same. But I want to save space, so I want to use a mutual method by inheriting it from another class. But I am doing something wrong.

Here is the code:

```
class Lullaby:
    def __init__(self, title, author, words):
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.words = words

class Functions:
    def __init__(self,Lullabies):
        def words(author=''):
            for i in Lullabies:
                if author in Lullabies.author:
                    print(Lullabies.words)
        self.words=words

class ENG():
    def __init__(self):
        Lullabies = [Lullaby('1','1',['word1','word2','word3']),Lullaby('2','2',['word4','word5','word6'])]
        self.words=Functions(Lullabies).words


class UA():
    def __init__(self):
        Lullabies = [Lullaby('1','1',['Слово1','Слово2','Слово3']),Lullaby('2','2',['Слово4','Слово5','Слово6'])]
        self.words = Functions(Lullabies).words

class Corpus():
    def __init__(self):
        self.ENG_Lullabies=ENG
        self.UA_Lullabies=UA

cor=Corpus()
print(cor.ENG_Lullabies.words('1'))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/myproject/Lullaby Corpus/TEST.py", line 32, in <module>
    print(cor.ENG_Lullabies.words('1'))
AttributeError: type object 'ENG' has no attribute 'words'
```

expected Output:

```
['word1','word2','word3']
```

Comment: `UA` doesn't inherit from `Lullabies`, so you can't use `super()`. Did you mean to inherit from `Functions` perhaps? You should not make `words` a nested function, however. It should just be a method, and the lullabies should be assigned as an attribute that `words()` would access on `self`.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to include the error you see. Please include the *expected* output, and what you get instead, full tracebacks for errors.

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake, but super() was not the problem, that class wasn't even called

Comment: Well, you didn't assign *instances* to the `Corpus` instance. You assigned classes. You really should not be using a class just to create a nested function, however.

Comment: I want to create a Corpus via a class (Corpus) that has two subcorpuses (ENG_Lullabies and UA_Lullabies), they both have a method "words" that returns the words by the author of the Lullaby.

Comment: You have to *instantiate* your child classes `ENG` and `UA` in `Corpus`, as in `self.ENG_Lullabies=ENG()`. Note the parentheses.

Comment: Okey, thank you it worked, I have one more question, I don't like the code I wrote, I mean this part (self.words=Functions(Lullabies).words), can I somehow inherit the method instead of reassigning it?

Comment: No need I've already have done it, I've inhereted the class Function and after assighnin Lullabies I passed the Lullabies via      super().__init__(Lullabies). Thank you for everything.

Answer (score 3):

You assigned *classes* to the `Corpus` attributes:

```
class Corpus():
    def __init__(self):
        self.ENG_Lullabies=ENG
        self.UA_Lullabies=UA
```

but the rest of your code expected instances. Call classes to create instances:

```
class Corpus():
    def __init__(self):
        self.ENG_Lullabies = ENG()
        self.UA_Lullabies = UA()
```

I strongly advice you to stick to [Python's naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions), and use `lower_case_with_underscores` for attributes and local variables, so it is clearer when you have a class and when you should be working with an instance.

Next, you should use *inheritance* to pull in methods from `Functions` (which I'd rename here to better reflect the purpose of the base class).

You also want to separate presentation from class functionality; don't print in the `words` method. Return the results, and then, where it makes sense, use `print()` to turn those results into user feedback. That way you can later on also use the same method to, say, write the results to a network socket or a file, or show them in a GUI:

```
class Lullaby:
    def __init__(self, title, author, words):
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.words = words

class LullabiesCollection:
    def __init__(self, lullabies):
        self.lullabies = lullabies

    def words(self, author=''):
        """Return the words of lullabies, in a list

        When author is given, limit the search to lullabies by author substring.

        """
        result = []
        for lullaby in self.lullabies:
            if not author or author in lullaby.author:
                result.append(lullaby.words)
        return result

class EnglishLullabies(LullabiesCollection):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__([
            Lullaby('1', '1', ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']),
            Lullaby('2', '2', ['word4', 'word5', 'word6'])
        ])

class UkranianLullabies(LullabiesCollection):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__([
            Lullaby('1', '1', ['Слово1', 'Слово2', 'Слово3']),
            Lullaby('2', '2', ['Слово4','Слово5','Слово6'])
        ])

class Corpus():
    def __init__(self):
        self.eng = EnglishLullabies()
        self.ua = UkranianLullabies()

cor = Corpus()
for words in cor.eng.words('1'):
    print(words)
```

Not that I think that `Corpus`, `EnglishLullabies` and `UkranianLullabies` actually need to be *classes*. Only create new classes if you are adding functionality; when just creating a grouping of lullabies, you don't need a new class.

The following would work too:

```
corpus = {
    'eng': LullabiesCollection([
        Lullaby('1', '1', ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']),
        Lullaby('2', '2', ['word4', 'word5', 'word6'])
    ]),
    'ua': LullabiesCollection([
        Lullaby('1', '1', ['Слово1', 'Слово2', 'Слово3']),
        Lullaby('2', '2', ['Слово4','Слово5','Слово6'])
    ]),
}
for words in corpus['eng'].words('1'):
    print(words)
```

Comment: There is an error in the function words, as it is not a part of the __init__ function it can't read self.lullabies

Comment: I found where is the problem. The words function needs to have self (def words(self, author=''))

Comment: Thank you, you've helped me a lot

Comment: @IgorDragushhak: Yes, sorry, I had indeed forgotten to add in the self parameter. Mea Culpa!